# Does "snide" mean something different in the US vs the UK?

Tags: differences

I'm a native British English speaker and to me the word "snide" (as in "a snide comment") conveys an idea of nastiness and maliciousness as well as slyness and underhandedness.

Does the word snide convey any of those ideas to speakers of US English?

I'm asking because I've come across a few comments online written by Americans where they used the word snide in a way that didn't make sense to me as a Brit in the contexts it was used.

Does snide have a slightly different meaning in US English or is it one of those words like ironically or literally that is sometimes used incorrectly by native speakers?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96692/discussion-on-question-by-hugh-jarce-does-snide-mean-something-different-in-th).

Answer (score 1):

I think Snide definitely implies some sort of nasty underhandedness - even in its definition:

dictionary.com:

> **Snide**
>
> Derogatory in a nasty, insinuating manner

Insinuating being the key word (from Merriam Webster) :

> **Insinuating**
>
> tending gradually to cause doubt, distrust, or change of outlook often
>   in a slyly subtle manner

Checking on [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows several uses where the sly/nasty element is involved:

> Snide murmurs followed that the global development director
>
> his snide way to flip her a fingerless bird
>
> Snide smiles behind her back were something with which she was quite
>   familiar

This shows a similar usage to what you describe as the UK context.

Comment: That corpus is a very useful resource, I've bookmarked that. Maybe the people in question just don't know what snide means and simply used the wrong word. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

snide, adj.
sneering or critical in a sly, not open manner.
(Kernerman English Multilingual Dictionary),
"not open" being the key word.

"snide" can also be attributed to people: 
snide, adj. - making or given to making snide remarks: a snide roommate. (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language).